# Contribution Confirmation Page Issue in Joomla after upgrade

Tags: contribution-page

Friends

I have upgraded a few Joomla sites to the new 5.37.2 version. Now on all sites, the contribution confirm page does not work. Irrespective 'Go Back' or 'Confirm Contribution' is clicked; you are immediately redirected to the home page. When I disable / deselect this confirmation page in the setup, the contribution gets recorded with no issue.

Thanks :)
Sri

Answer (score 2):

After a long search and resetting paths and clearing cache and checking the .setting files 100s of times the issue was not with the site URL vs the .setting URLS being different aliases as pointed by many of the answers found; it was a damn malware!! 3 sites with the same phishing link in the defines.php in the includes folder. Who would have guessed that. Ths submissions were attempted to be redirected and civi pushes it back to the home page.

As always curse the virus and malware creators!!